# Is this a feasible matrix decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, matrix-decomposition

Suppose that I observe an $N\times N$ matrix $D$. $D$ is equal to $X'Y$ for two $K\times N$ matrices $X$ and $Y$.

Suppose also that $K\leq N/2$, so that I have more moments ($N^2$) than parameters ($2NK$).

Is it possible to solve for $X$ and $Y$ in general? Alternatively, supposing that the system doesn't hold exactly, is there a good algorithm for solving

$$\min_{X,Y} \vert \vert (D-X'Y) \vert \vert^2 $$

Comment: You're right, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $X' = X^T$, then the rank of $X^TY$ will be at most $K$ so it may not be possible to solve the system $($if, for instance, $D$ has rank $>K)$.

Now, given an $m\times n$ matrix $M$ with rank $\leqslant r$, there is an $m\times r$ matrix $C$ and an $r\times n$ matrix $R$ with $M=CR$. See 'Decomposition rank' in the linked section of [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Alternative_definitions).
This ensures that you can look to minimize

$$\min {\lVert D - D_K\rVert}^2, \tag{$*$}$$

where $D_K\in \Bbb R^{N\times N}$ has rank at most $K$.
If you do find a minimizer, it is guaranteed that you can write $D_K = X^TY$ with matching dimensions.

The good news is that the set $S_K$ of matrices with rank at most $K$ is closed.
See, for instance, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/43194/173410).
It is essentially a consequence of the rank being the largest size of a non-vanishing minor (also described in the linked section of the Wikipedia article above).

So the problem in $(*)$ is about minimizing the distance between a compact set $\big(\{D\}\big)$ and a closed set $(S_K)$.
It follows that the infimum is attained, that is, there *is* some $D_K$ which minimizes $(*)$.

The set $S_K$, however, is not convex, and indeed its convex hull is the entire space.
I don't know how you'd go about finding the minimizer algorithmically, it is out of my area of expertise.