# Is the set of matrices with rank at most $2$ closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, metric-spaces, matrix-rank

Let $$S := \left\{ {\bf X} \in \Bbb R^{4 \times 4} \mid \operatorname{rank} ({\bf X}) \leq 2 \right\}$$ Is $S$ closed with respect to the usual Euclidean metric?

---

I think so. My reasoning is the following:

Let $({\bf A}_n)$ be a sequence in $S$ converging to a matrix $\bf A$. We observe that the row operations performed in order to get row echelon form are continous.   Let ${\bf A}'_n$ denote the row echelon form of ${\bf A}_n$. Since the rank is preserved, there are at most two nonzero rows in ${\bf A}'_n$. Let ${\bf A}'_n = \phi({\bf A}_n)$ for some continous function $\phi.$ Since $A_n$ converges, we must have that ${\bf A}_n'$ converges. Since ${\bf A}'_n$ converges, it follows that its corresponding entries also converge, so the limiting matrix will have at most $2$ nonzero rows, or equivalently, a rank of at most $2$. The limit matrix must be the row echelon form of ${\bf A}$, so ${\bf A}$ is in $S$.

Is there any problem with the above argument?

Comment: How do you prove your claim that "the row operations performed in order to get row echelon form are continous"?

Comment: Could you also clarify exactly what metric you are referring to? I'm not sure there is something like a standard Euclidean metric on the set of matrices.

Comment: Hint: all minors of size 3 vanish for a matrix with rank at most 2

Comment: @StinkingBishop I'm not sure but my reasoning would be this: The steps transforming $A_n$ to $A_n'$ are all linear, so the entire transformation is linear and thus continous since we are in a finite dimensional space. But the linear map $A_n$ to $A_n'$ is possibly a different one for each $n$, so we can't assume that there is _one_ continous function $phi$ that maps $A_n$ to $A_n'$. But then again it's probably trivial to construct a linear map between any two (non-zero) vector space elements so I guess this argument is not of much value.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Row operations use just addition, multiplication by scalars and swapping of entries which is easy to see as continous functions in $\mathbb{R}^{16}$.

Comment: @pauwelvde You may think collection of $n \times n$ matrices as euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ with usual metric.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that the collection of rank-k matrices forms a closed subset of the space of matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43192/how-to-prove-that-the-collection-of-rank-k-matrices-forms-a-closed-subset-of-the)

Comment: @daw No, I want to check validity of my argument.

Comment: @3f183201 For proof-verification question, please use the proper tag

Comment: @Didier You may see the original the question, there was solution verification tag, but later someone removed it  I guess.

Comment: @3f183201 Right, sorry about that!

Comment: @3f183201 Sorry for not getting back to you earlier. I see you've got some answers already. The bottom line is that you are not using _just_ elementary operations, you also need to choose _which_ operations to use, depending on whether a particular element in the matrix is nonzero. Imagine the situation where the top left corner converges to zero: $$(A_n)_{11}=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{n}&n\text{ even}\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ In even $A_n$ you multiply the $1$st row by $n$, in odd ones you may swap the first row with something, or do something entirely different...

Comment: (Cont'd) In effect I think you are making the same error as someone who, from knowing that $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=1$ are continuous functions concludes that $$h(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&x=0\\g(x)&x\ne 0\end{cases}$$ is also continuous, which obviously does not follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that your proof is correct. You claim that there is a "universal sequence of row operations" transforming **all** matrices into echelon form. But it seems to me that we need different sequences of row operations for different matrices. Only if you can prove that there actually exists a universal sequence of row operations, you would get a continuous function $\phi$ assigning to each matrix $A$ a matrix $\phi(A)$ in echelon form. I doubt that, but maybe I am wrong.

So what can be done? I think Didier's comment is an essential ingredient. We know that a matrix $A$ has rank $\le 2$ iff all $3 \times 3$-minors $A^{i,j}$ obtained from $A$ by eliminating row $i$ and column $j$ have vanishing determinant. Now consider a sequence $(A_n)$ of matrices with rank $\le 2$ which converges to a matrix $A$. Consider all sequences $(A^{i,j}_n)$ of $3 \times 3$-minors. They converge to the minors $A^{i,j}$ of $A$. Since the determinant is continuous, all $A^{i,j}$ have vanishing determinant which means that $A$ has rank $\le 2$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to address only your posted question, regarding whether there is a problem with your argument.

Yes, there is a big problem.

It is true that any individual row operation is a continuous operation on the space of $4 \times 4$ matrices, i.e. a continuous function $\mathbb R^{16} \mapsto \mathbb R^{16}$. This is true for more-or-less the reason you explained in the comments. The way I would say it is that an individual row operation is just left-multiplication by an individual elementary matrix $E$: $EA$ is the result of applying the given row operation to $A$, and when $E$ is fixed, $EA$ is a continuous function of $A$.

And it is still true that if one **fixes** one particular sequence of row operations, then that fixed sequence represents a continuous function on the space of $4 \times 4$ matrices. By fixing the sequence of row operations, one is fixing a sequence of elementary matrices $E_1,...,E_k$ to multiply on the left by: $E_1 A$ is the result of applying the first row operation, $E_2 E_1 A$ is the result of applying the second row operation, and so on. Taking the product of that sequence elementary matrices $M = E_k \cdots E_1$ one gets a fixed invertible matrix to multiply on the left by: $MA$ is the row echelon form of $A$, and $MA$ is a continuous function of $A$.

One way that this is summarized in linear algebra is by the "$LU$-factorization theorem": for every matrix $A$ there is a factorization $A=LU$ where $U$ is the echelon form of $A$, and $L$ is a square, invertible matrix, and $M=L^{-1}$ is the product of the sequence of elementary matrices that are used in the row reduction process.

But here's the big problem. Suppose that I take two different matrices ${\bf A}_m$ and ${\bf A}_n$ in your sequence. There is no reason at all to expect their row operation sequences to be the same. In fact, it is certainly possible that every single matrix has a row operation sequence different from the others. One can express this in the language of the $LU$ factorization theorem: we do get factorizations ${\bf A}_n = L_n U_n$, and so we do get factorizations $L_n^{-1} {\bf A}_n = U_n$ where $M_n = L_n^{-1}$ is the product of the elementary matrices used to get ${\bf A}_n$ into row echelon form. But it is possible that every single $M_n$ matrix is different from the others.

Now, ***IF*** we knew that all of the $M_n$'s were the same then, perhaps, your argument could be made to work.

But that's a big ***IF***. More likely, all of the $M_n$'s are not all the same, and your argument fails.